# Retrieving an object into django templatetags.

Tags: django, templatetags

I would like to have a templatetags where I could deal with my object's fields.
So in my template I have something like :

```
{% myTag item %}
```

And in my templatetags :

```
@register.tag
    def myTag (parser,token):
        tag_name, item = token.split_contents()
        ...
```

However, token.split_contents() return me a string. 
How can I do to have my object instead of a string ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `tag` decorator, which needs a separate Node class in order to resolve variables. Instead, use the `simple_tag` decorator, which is passed the parameters directly.

```
@register.simple_tag
def myTag(item):
    ...
```